# App crashed when using setText method

Tags: android

Problem: My app crashed whenever the comment part is removed. But after I had tried to debug the problem seemed to be at line priceTextViews[i].setText(price[i]). Can anyone help to point out the problem? Thank you

```
TextView[] quantityTextViews;
TextView[] priceTextViews;
int[] unitPrice = {5, 15, 40, 20, 25, 15, 20, 25, 10, 20};
int[] price = new int[10];
int[] quantity = new int[10];

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.balance_page);

    textView();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String[] quantityOfItemString = intent.getStringArrayExtra    (ShoppingPageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    for (int i = 0; i < quantityTextViews.length; i++) {
        quantityTextViews[i].setText(quantityOfItemString[i]);
        quantity[i] = Integer.parseInt(quantityOfItemString[i]);
        price[i]= unitPrice[i]* quantity[i];
    }


    /*for (int i = 0; i < priceTextViews.length; i++) {
            price[i]= unitPrice[i]* quantity[i];
            priceTextViews[i].setText(price[i]);
    }*/
}

public void textView() {
    quantityTextViews = new TextView[]{
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView49),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView48),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView47),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView46),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView45),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView44),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView43),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView42),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView41),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView40),
    };

    priceTextViews = new TextView[]{
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView51),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView52),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView53),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView54),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView55),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView56),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView57),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView58),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView59),
            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView50),
    };
}
```

Comment: where is your crash log?

Comment: textView.set(String.valueOf(intValue)); This will work

Comment: Thanks, ebraley had helped me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setText requires a string. The setText method that does accept an int needs to correspond to a text resource within your application.

`priceTextViews[i].setText(Integer.toString(price[i]));`

Comment: @Lance the version you were using accepts an int, but it has to correspond to a resource string within your application.

Comment: Okay, i get what you mean. Thanks haha

Comment: This can't be the problem because you can't compile if argument types don't match.

Comment: @FatihOzcan it can accept an int, it's just that the int has to correspond to a resource.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, yes it accepts int type for resource id, it has overloaded methods.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using setText with int argument it automatically use `setText(@StringRes int resid)` instead of `void setText(CharSequence text)`, so cast your argument to String or similar CharSequence type.

Easiest solution is

```
priceTextViews[i].setText("" + price[i]);
```